# Flutter push notification: After receiving the first notification, the second notification is delayed and the app becomes unresponsive

Tags: flutter, push-notification

`
await Firebase.initializeApp(
name: 'Ryba', options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(messageHandler);

await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
alert: false,
badge: false,
sound: false,
);`